# How to start setInterval loop immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

In a simple `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function() {
      // Do something every 9 seconds
}, 9000);
```

The first action will happen after 9 seconds (`t=9s`). How to force the loop to perform the first action immediately (`t=0`)?

I think it is due to the mechanism of `setInterval` to have `Delay - Action - Delay - Action ...` loop; instead of `Action - Delay - Action - Delay ...` loop.

**EDIT:** My function is indeed a loop as

```
setInterval(function(){
$('.test').each(function(idx){
    var duration = 1000;
    $(this).delay(duration*idx);
    Some stuff here
});
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Whoever evented JavaScript hates the DRY principal.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Keep it simple. You can use a named function instead of an anonymous function; call it and set an interval for it.

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log("tick");
}
doSomething();
setInterval(doSomething, 9000);
```

Create a scope if necessary:

```
(function() {
    function doSomething() {
        console.log("tick");
    }
    doSomething();
    setInterval(doSomething, 9000);
})();
```

Finally, the following works without creating or affecting `x`:

```
setInterval(function x() {
    console.log("tick");
    return x;
}(), 9000);
```

Comment: The first part of this answer will get progressively slower, as a new `setInterval` is made every loop. This could be fixed by replacing `window.setInterval` with `setTimeout`.

Comment: I wonder how the 2nd sample would work with a lambda function?

Answer (score 29):

Sometimes I use this pattern...

```
(function me() {
    // Do something every 9 seconds

    setTimeout(me, 9000);
})();
```

It's not quite the same, as it will wait until the *do something* is executed before waiting ~9 seconds to call it again. But, this is often useful so events on the event queue do not stack up needlessly (however unlikely it is some code will take 9 seconds to run :)

Note that in older IEs, the `me` will leak to the outside scope.

Comment: *"Note that in older IEs, the me will leak to the outside scope."* And two different functions are created, at different times, with the same code. The *first* time your code runs, it's one of them; all the subsequent times it's the other one. Weird but true.

Comment: I wish this worked seamlessly on all browsers. It's just so clean. Which versions of IE malfunction?

Comment: @thekingoftruth It should *work* seamlessly, it will just leak the `me` identifier in IE. From memory, it's <= IE8 that has an issue.

Comment: @alex I can live with that. :) I wonder if `(var me = function(){...` would work as well. edit: ah, I see that it will not.

Comment: @thekingoftruth `var <name> = <something>` is `undefined`, whereas `<name> = <something>` is `<name>` (which is effectively equal to `<something>`. So you can do `var me; (me = function() { … })()`.

Comment: You have a recursion loop that will add one call to the callstack every time it runs. Eventually, you will hit the maximum call stack size and your app will crash. 

https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Too_much_recursion

Comment: Nice trick. But it won't be long before some messes up this code and introduce some bugs.

Answer (score 21):

I use this sanitized version of `setInterval`, which does call the function immediately, and takes a time in seconds, BEFORE the function parameter so calling it with an inline function definition actually looks sensible.

```
function startInterval(seconds, callback) {
  callback();
  return setInterval(callback, seconds * 1000);
}
```

Comment: If callback calls clearInterval(), it will always fail to clear the interval in the first call with this implementation. 

What would work is: `const id = setInterval(...); setTimeout(callback); return id;` this ensures that the intervalId is not undefined in the first call to callback

Answer (score 5):

Use a named function and call it and assign it to the interval.

```
var myFnc = function() {
    // Do something every 9 seconds
};
setInterval(myFnc, 9000);
myFnc();
```

The other option is to use setTimeout instead.

```
var myFnc = function() {
    // Do something every 9 seconds
    setTimeout(myFnc, 9000);
};
myFnc();
```

Comment: That's not a named function. It's an anonymous function assigned to a variable. The *variable* has a name, the function does not (which is fine for what you're doing, other than that some debuggers won't be able to show you a useful name in call stacks and such [others do, the latest Chrome Dev Tools and Firebug are quite smart]).