# How can i eliminate this delay when it is called for the first time?

Tags: jquery

I am calling a function for every 10 minutes this way

```
var int=self.setInterval(my_func, 600000);


function my_func(){

$.ajax({
         url: 'xxxxxxxx',
        success: function(response) {
    var data= JSON.parse(response);
    displayCustomerDetails(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('Error full filling request');
        }
    }); 

}
```

How can i eliminate this delay when it is called for the first time ??

Comment: `my_func();` to call it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
my_func();    
var int=self.setInterval(my_func, 600000);
```

But 10 minutes for `setInterval` is pretty high. You may want to read about Ajax Push Engines (aka APE) - [check this out](http://ape-project.org/).

Also, it looks like this question is similar: [How to start setInterval loop immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563344/how-to-start-setinterval-loop-immediately)